# WaitForControlEnabled() throws UITestControlNotFoundException

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

I'm waiting for a control to be enabled like this:

```
control.WaitForControlEnabled(60000); // timeout in 60 seconds
```

However, sometimes about ten seconds in this method would throw a `UITestControlNotFoundException`:

```
Test method MyTest threw exception:
Automation Playback Engine was not able to find the button &Next > in - window &Next >. Additional Details: TechnologyName: 'MSAA' Name: 'Next >' ControlType: 'Button'
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.UITestControlNotFoundException
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Playback.MapControlNotFoundException(COMException ex, IPlaybackContext context)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Playback.MapAndThrowComException(COMException innerException, IPlaybackContext context)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Playback.MapAndThrowException(Exception exception, IPlaybackContext context)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Playback.MapAndThrowException(Exception exception, String queryId)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.FindFirstDescendant(String queryId, Boolean expandUIElementWhileSearching, Int32 searchTime)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.SearchHelper.GetElement(Boolean useCache, ISearchArgument searchArg)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.SearchHelper.Search(ISearchArgument searchArg)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.FindInternal()
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.FindControlIfNecessary()
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.WaitForControlReadyPrivate(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, Boolean doLogging)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.WaitForControlEnabledPrivate(Int32 millisecondsTimeout)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl+<>c__DisplayClass4a.<WaitForControlEnabled>b__49()
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.CodedUITestMethodInvoker.InvokeMethod(Func`1 function, UITestControl control, Boolean firePlaybackErrorEvent, Boolean logAsAction)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.WaitForControlEnabled(Int32 millisecondsTimeout)

    Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
        at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Playback.Engine.IScreenElement.FindAllDescendants(String bstrQueryId, Object& pvarResKeys, Int32 cResKeys, Int32 nMaxDepth)
        at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Playback.ScreenElement.FindAllScreenElement(String queryId, Int32 depth, Boolean singleQueryId, Boolean throwException, Boolean resetSkipStep)
        at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Playback.ScreenElement.FindScreenElement(String queryId, Int32 depth, Boolean resetSkipStep)
        at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.FindFirstDescendant(String queryId, Boolean expandUIElementWhileSearching, Int32 searchTime)
```

My questions are:

- Why doesn't `WaitForControlEnabled(60000)` wait for the whole 60 seconds?
- Why does it throw `UITestControlNotFoundException` even though that is not mentioned in the [MSDN doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee379417(v=vs.110).aspx)?

**Edit:** I have used `WaitForControlExist()` directly before `WaitForControlEnabled()`, however `WaitForControlEnabled()` still throws the same exception, which makes no sense to me:

```
control.WaitForControlExist(60000);
control.WaitForControlEnabled(60000);
```

If `WaitForControlExist()` returns, then that means the UI element was found. But then how can it not be found immediately after?

Answer (score 0):

To wait until the time you specified in the WaitForControlEnabled() method, the top hierarchy of the controls should be exist or the actual control must be exist or in disabled state, otherwise the smart search engine fails to find the waiting control and throws the exception. If the control is not there you can try WaitForControlNotExist() method to wait until the control exist, Because I also found the same issue in my test cases, here is my solution to wait for a control even for an hour of time until it
exit or enabled.

```
        bool iscontrolexist= uIwaitingButton.WaitForControlEnabled();

        while (!iscontrolexist)
        {
            try
            {
             uIwaitingButton.SearchConfigurations.Add(SearchConfiguration.AlwaysSearch);
             uIwaitingButton.SetFocus(); // setting focus for the on button
             iscontrolexist= uIwaitingButton.WaitForControlExist(100);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               // possibly exception for setfocus() method call 
               // handle exception, to write a log message                   
            }

        }

        // perform the button click after find the control
        // Click 'Save' button
        Mouse.Click(uIwaitingButton, new Point(100,100));
```